# Test for significant difference in ratios of sample means

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, statistical-significance, mean, likelihood-ratio

I have the same scenario here: [Test for significant difference in ratios of normally distributed random variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23152/test-for-significant-difference-in-ratios-of-normally-distributed-random-variabl)

Suppose I have to compare a metric that is a ratio of two sample means for men and women. 
$$
H_{0}:
\frac{\overline{X}_{men}}{\overline{Y}_{men}}>
\frac{\overline{X}_{women}}{\overline{Y}_{women}}
$$
What is the test statistic of this hypothesis? I was not able to figure out what kind of distribution it is.
I have tried to use permutation test and it worked fine but I have a lot sample means for different group to compare with and permutation test performs pretty slow. Thanks!

Comment: Nonparametric approach, like Wilcoxon test, maybe?

Comment: I'll try to study Wilcoxon test. And I just think of log transformation. Is this a right approach?

Comment: Averages are random variables, while statistical hypotheses apply only to parameters. Do you want to test E(X)/E(Y), or (more likely) E(X/Y)? These are two different questions.

Comment: X/Y should be a Cauchy distribution if I'm not mistaken? But what I want to test is E(X)/E(Y) and not E(X/Y). So I need a nonparametric approach to test it like @ŁukaszDeryło mentioned?