# Comparing distributions of ratios between two samples

Tags: proportion, ratio

I have a dataset structured something like this - obviously the numbers are exaggerated and I actually have hundreds of observations in each group.

Group 1:

| Observation | Number of specific items | Total items | Proportion of specific to total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Obs1 | 10 | 100 | .10 |
| Obs2 | 20 | 190 | .11 |
| Obs3 | 15 | 160 | .09 |

Group 2:

| Observation | Number of specific items | Total items | Proportion of specific to total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Obs4 | 150 | 500 | .30 |
| Obs5 | 13 | 50 | .26 |
| Obs6 | 75 | 250 | .30 |

In this case, each observation has a different total number of items and that number can vary a lot between observations.

I want to compare the Proportion of Specific Items (last column) between the two groups. The hypothesis is that the Proportion of Specific Items is different between the two groups. Essentially, I believe it is a comparison of means of the Proportion of Specific Items columns, but I'm concerned that a t-test is not the right test in this case due to that column being a proportion or a ratio of Specific Items to Total Items.

A t-test doesn't seem correct since I'm comparing proportional values but a Z-test doesn't make sense because I have multiple observations and cannot make a simple 2x2 contingency table.

Some additional clarifications and details:

Each of the count variables is expected to be distributed as a normal random variable.  However, the two are surely correlated since increased total numbers of items would imply increased specific items as well, at least for this particular problem.

Doing a little more research I found the [Ratio Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution).  This seems to fit quite nicely and there is a reference to a solution for the distribution of correlated random normal variables.  ([Hinkley 1969](https://academic.oup.com/biomet/article-abstract/56/3/635/233807?redirectedFrom=fulltext&login=false))

Further, similar questions have been asked here:

[Test for significant difference in ratios of normally distributed random variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23152/test-for-significant-difference-in-ratios-of-normally-distributed-random-variabl)

[A/B testing ratio of sums](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/398436/a-b-testing-ratio-of-sums)

Based on these results, I feel like my instinct that the t-test is not appropriate was correct.  There does not appear to be a specific test for this, however.  Some suggestions included the Delta Method (I need to study this one closer to feel comfortable with the math), and a permutation test to create an empirical null distribution.

The permutation test made me think of non-parametric approaches.  Something like a Wilcoxon Rank-Sum test seems like it might be appropriate here, and given the number of observations (500+ in each group), I'm not too concerned about loss of power with such a test.

I appreciate any feedback on using a non-parametric test in this case.

**EDIT:**
Added some clarifying text from my comment.  Thanks to @whuber for asking for the clarification which very much helped me to better frame my question.

**EDIT:**
Add some additional clarification regarding the distributions of variables, correlation, etc.

Comment: Please tell us what comparisons you wish to make.  There is no natural pairing between the groups to suggest what those might be and the answer depends on *exactly* which comparisons you have in mind.

Comment: I want to compare the Proportion of Specific Items (last column) between the two groups.  The hypothesis is that the Proportion of Specific Items is different between the two groups.  Essentially, I believe it is a comparison of means of the Proportion of Specific Items columns, but I'm concerned that a t-test is not the right test in this case due to that column being a proportion or a ratio of Specific Items to Total Items.